# mongodb not starting after reboot for my rails3 app

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Due to power outage my computer crahsed while working on rails3 app. My mongodb is not restarting ever since.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10
connecting to: test
 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

Noticed after reboot /data/db is missing. Went ahead and created it, but for some reason it is still not starting. Appreciate inputs here

Comment: Are you getting this error when trying to run mongo instance in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is due to mongodb lock.

Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

and restart your service.